# How to store the images to the app in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

```
    @IBAction func btnClicked(){

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Choose an option", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cameraRollAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera Roll", style: .Default) { (action) in
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
    alertController.addAction(cameraRollAction)

    let takePictureAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a picture", style: .Default) { (action) in
        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self.imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
        self.imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
        self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(takePictureAction)



}
```

How can I store the images to the app that I am selecting from the device? Whenever I select the images it appears but when I close and reopen the app the image disappears.

Comment: you can save image in Document directory. or u can save image data in UserDefaults.

Comment: you need to save the image in backend server or Document directory or use local database

Comment: see this link http://helpmecodeswift.com/image-manipulation/saving-loading-images

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could be that you can save the images in the app's document directory. And all the paths to those images can be stored in NSUserDefaults.

Check this link for saving images to document directory :

[Click me !](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-save-a-uiimage-to-a-file-using-uiimagepngrepresentation)

Add your NSUserDefaults logic accordingly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here an example how to store an image

```
    let image:UIImage = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: "someImagePath")!//here it will be the image that you get from the pickerController
    let data:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)!
    data .writeToFile("file_Path", atomically: true)
```

**EDIT**

you have implement this protocol of UIImagePickerViewContoller

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info;
```

in info dictionary you will find the Image.
so you can put the code example above in the protocol implementation.

Comment: So can I give the above code to the image button action? @BEN MESSAOUD

Comment: you have implement this protocol of UIImagePickerViewContoller
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info;

Answer (score 0):

if you need to store a number of different images, then you should have a look at database options - here's a good tutorial on CoreData http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial but if you only need to store a single image per app, then you could do that as part of storing the user defaults, and there's a good tutorial available for that as well http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data